# How to set a different cooldown for different users like dank memer?

Tags: python, discord.py

If you have ever used dank memer you must have seen that premium members can use a few commands with a lower command cooldown than the regular non-premium users. I want to achieve this same thing in discord.py. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

To add a cooldown for a command you need to use the `@commands.cooldown()` decorator. You can set a simple cooldown like this:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
```

The previous decorator adds a ratelimit of 1 use every 30 seconds for each user.
If what you want is to have different cooldowns you can change the `BucketType` to put a cooldown only for a specific role or even for a specific member. You could also create a new `BucketType` to add some kind of *premium users*.

References:

- [@commands.cooldown()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)
- [BucketTypes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.discord.ext.commands.BucketType)